# Sharepoint 2013 - How to export Most Popular Items to excel?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, export-to-excel

I am not aware of an OOTB feature to export the Most Popular Items search query to excel.

How may this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge you may need to do it manually with PowerShell.

In Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics namespace, there is a method “[UsageAnalytics.GetAnalyticsItemData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj252085(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)” which can help to “Retrieves aggregated usage data for a specified item for a specified event type”.

You may use it as a start point.

Comment: Thanks Jerry - I was hoping to find a simpler way.

Comment: @garvon-77 As another option, you may need to call search REST API to get the results for most popular items. Reference link for custom code:https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-most-visited-sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/#sthash.ETDAKw1Y.dpuf